# Draw tree-like figure

Tags: draw

How do I draw a tree-like figure similar to the one below please?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add a MWE of your current code. The `forest` package should work for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some ideas coming from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142296/184389), you can obtain such a structure like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}


    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        sibling distance = 10em,
        every node/.style = {%
            shape = rectangle,
            align = center,
            draw
        },
        edge from parent fork down
    ]

        \node {Main Tree}
            child {node {Sub-tree 1\\{\scriptsize Some text}}}
            child {node {Sub-tree 2\\{\scriptsize Some text}}}
            child {node {Sub-tree 3\\{\scriptsize Some text}}};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can adapt the distance between the nodes at the same level by changing the value of the `sibling distance` option and you can also change the distance between two levels by adding a `level distance` option.
Finally, you can change the way your nodes are display by adding to the `every node` style.

For more, you can refer to the PGF/TikZ documentation and more precisely, to the `trees` library sections.

Comment: Thank you so much, you have been great help.

Answer (score 2):

With `forest` is simple:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
    draw, 
    text width= 22mm,
    text centered,
%    
    s sep = 3mm,
    l sep = 4mm,
    forked edge,
    fork sep=2mm
            }
[Main Tree
    [Sub-tree 1\\   \scriptsize Some text]
    [Sub-tree 2\\   \scriptsize Some text]
    [Sub-tree 3\\   \scriptsize Some text]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]